# How to make a vertical input field?

Tags: html, css

This is what I want. A vertical input field, the 'x' is the close button:

[image]

This is what I have so far:

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
html,body{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
.sidenav{
  height:100%;
  width:20%;
  background:#111;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding:calc((20% - 50px)/2);
}
.sidenav a{
  position:relative;
  bottom:18px;
  font-size:90px;
  color:#818181;
}
```

```html
<div class='sidenav''>
  <a>&times</a>
</div>
```

I know how to make a regular, bare-boned html input field:

```html
<form>
  <input type=text placeholder='enter name'></input>
  <input type='submit' id='submit'></input>
</form>
```

**EDIT**: I want to integrate it to make a stylistically uniform, like this search bar from CodePen:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may take a look at [`writing-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode).

> The writing-mode CSS property defines whether lines of text are laid out horizontally or vertically and the direction in which blocks progress.

About MSIE https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms531187(v=vs.85).aspx

```css
.sideway {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  writing-mode: sideways-lr;/* FF*/
  background: gray;
  padding: 0.25em;
  vertical-align:top;
}

form {
  border: solid gray
  }
```

```html
<form><span class="sideway">
  <input type=text placeholder='enter name' size=8/>
  <input type='submit' id='X'/>
  </span>
</form>
```

`<edit>` *Chrome does not apply writing-mode on form element (bug?)*

Work around possible: [**demo**](https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/gxyZom)

```css
.sideway {
  font-size: 3em;
  margin: 0 1em 0 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: #333;
  padding: 0.25em 0;
  float: left;
  width: 2em;
}
.sideway span {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translatey(100%) rotate(270deg);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
.sideway span:before {
  content: '';
  padding-top: 100%;
  float: left;
}
input {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: gray;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  line-height: 0.8em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  outline: none;
}
[type="submit"] {
  font-size: 2em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width:1em;
}
form {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: solid #333 0.5em;
}
p {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <p class="sideway">
    <span>
       <input type=text placeholder='enter name' size=8/>
       <input type='submit' id='submit' value='&times'/>
    </span>
  </p>
  <p>whatever else comes in your form</p>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you integrate it to make it stylistically uniform? I edited my question to show an example.

Comment: @user132522 sorry, i do not understand what you mean ? inputs can be style anyway you like. it doesn't matter wich size it takes, it will grow taller or smaller itself :) You might have to reset width on p if you let it go on few lines or add images taller than text

Comment: Yeah, that was what I was talking about. I will take a look at it.

Answer (score 8):

What you're looking for is [**`transform: rotate()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform).This takes a value in degrees, so you can rotate either to the left or to the right. `rotate(90deg)` goes from top to bottom, `rotate(-90deg)` goes from bottom to top.

You'll also probably want to make use of **[`transform-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin)** to choose where the rotation gets **based** from, in order for the rotated text to align at the correct position.

Here's a minimal example:

```css
input[type="text"] {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: left 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' placeholder='enter name'>
```

And here's a (rough) working example. Maximise the snippet to see it positioned correctly. You may need to adapt the positioning based on your page layout.

```css
input[type="text"] {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -150%;
  left: 25%;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: left 0;
}

form {
  position: relative;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  background: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: calc((20% - 50px)/2);
}

.sidenav a {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 18px;
  font-size: 90px;
  color: #818181;
}
```

```html
<div class='sidenav'>
  <form>
    <input type='text' placeholder='enter name '>
    <a>&times</a>
  </form>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: How do you integrate it into the background? Look at my question edit.