# Is there a way to make text input that aligns vertically?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to be able to write text and have it both vertical and upright, I've been able to get it working with CSS like so:

```
writing-mode: vertical-lr;
text-orientation: upright;
```

But I've only gotten in to work for the p tag. Problem is that I want to be able to have a text input like that, through either textarea or some kind of input form, with the text starting at the upper left corner, gets written downwards and then when the text hits the bottom of the textarea it starts on the right side of that text, so a user could write directly on the page like

```
T  R
H  I
I  G
S  H
   T
T  
E  H  
X  E
T  R
   E
```

I've searched through Stack and found some ideas that make it work, for static text written in the code, but nothing for textarea or form.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355557/how-to-vertically-align-text-in-input-type-text) answer your question? This is not yet supported over input fields.

Comment: Use <p> tag or <div> and make it content editable. And apply style to make text it vertical.

Comment: Thank you Yuvraj! got it working with contentEditable="true" on a <div> :)

Answer (score 0):

i never done what you are asking for, but i suggest to put an eye on

```
display: flex
```

with

```
flex-flow: column wrap;
```

I guess that is not the right idea for forms, put an eye on this page, it have different possibilities

[How to make a vertical input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46062705/how-to-make-a-vertical-input-field)